# Android application with multiple raster layers in offline mode

Tags: raster, software-recommendations, android, offline

I would like to create an android application where we can view and control visibilities of various raster layers such as orthomosaic layer, DSM layer, contour map layer created from drone images of an area.

The application should support the following features

1. View high resolution map using orthophoto
2. Manage (show/hide) visibility of DSM,contour map layers.
3. Map rotation (for top view and perspective view)
4. Distance measurement
5. Elevation measurement using elevation layer

Can anyone please help me understand how this can be achieved in an android application? I have checked the QGIS desktop app and could see all these functionalities.

I am looking for an open source android library to render the high resolution image and perform the above mentioned functionalities. I have checked the https://github.com/moagrius/TileView sdk. But it don't support layer rotation.

Can anyone please suggest any android sdk to be used for the purpose?

Comment: What Android SDKs have you found in your research?  Which have you investigated?  Which got the closest to meeting your requirements?  What was the showstopper requirement that prevented you proceeding to (further) testing?

Comment: @PolyGeo I could only find ArcGIS runtime SDK for android to meet my requirements. But the raster functionality is in beta for mobile platforms at version 100.0.0. I would like to know if there is any open source sdk that can meet my requirements. I am new to the world of GIS and wish if someone can provide me with some help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with any requested clarifications.